# Fetch column name from hive via querygrid

Tags: teradata, struts2-jquery-grid

My requirement is that I need to fetch only the list of columns of a hive table via querygrid.

For example, the "help foreign table" gives the col_name,data_type and comment as output.

Can someone please suggest how I can fetch only the col_name?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below in hive

`show columns in <table name>`

this should return you a list of columns in a table.

Comment: This is in hive. I need to fetch it in my teradata using querygrid

Comment: Ok then why did you tag HIVE into this?

Comment: Because its a hive table which needs to be accessed via querygrid